How to find the number of values of {$a,b,c,d$} satisfying the following condition
How to find the number of values of {$a,b,c,d$} such that the following condition holds :
$$a+b^{2}+c^{3}+d^{4}=1000(a)+100(b)+10(c)+d$$
$a\in[1,9]$
$b\in[0,9]$
$c\in[0.9]$
$d\in [0,9]$
The value of $a$ is from $[1,9]$ because if $a=0$ then $abcd$ will be a $3$ digit number.
My try :
First of all I was doing it by trial and error method. That is I was assuming some $4$ digit numbers arbitrarily and checking whether the given condition is being satisfied or not.
Finally I found only one number and that is $1306$.
Because
$1^{1}+3^{2}+0^{3}+6^{4}=1000(1)+100(3)+10(0)+(6)$
Secondly when the trial and error method was not working then I was thinking of taking cases to solve.
Let me tell some cases.
Let's assume that $a=1$. Now $b,c,d$ can be any values between $[0,9]$
Therefore some cases will be like
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1$
$a=1, b=2, c=2, d=2$
$a=1, b=3, c=3, d=3$
And so on upto $$a=1, b=9, c=9, d=9$$
I assumed the condition that $b=c=d$
Now  let's assume the condition $$b=c$$
That is the conditions will be
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1$
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=2$
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=3$
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=4$
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=5$
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=6$
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=7$
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=8$
$a=1, b=1, c=1, d=9$
Now I again have to check for the condition $b=c=2$ ; $b=c=3$ ; $b=c=4$ ; and so on $b=c=9$
Now the main problem here is I have just considered $a=1$ now.
Similarly there will be many other cases for $a=2,3,4,...,9$
So, the total number of cases are huge.
So, this method is not helping at all.
3rd Method :
It is given that $$a+b^{2}+c^{3}+d^{4}=1000(a)+100(b)+10(c)+d$$
Now we can write that $$b^{2}-100(b)+c^{3}-10(c)+d^4-d=999(a)$$
Therefore I can say that the L.H.S. should be a multiple of $999$ which again implies that the L.H.S. should be a multiple of $9$ because $999$ is divisible by $9$.
But then again I have to take cases for $b,c,d$ . That is $b\in [0,9], c\in [0,9], d\in [0,9]$
But that is also difficult one.
So, please help me out. I just found only $3$ methods and surprisingly all are difficult.

You can reduce the range of $a \in [1,7]$ because $RHS = LHS \le 9 + 9^2 + 9^3 + 9^4 = 7380$, then $a \le 7$

You won't find a lot of solutions, I only found less than five but I cheated and used a computer.

Also, $d\in[4, 9]$ since $9+9^2+9^3+3^4 = 900 < 1000$.

@IIT Roorkee: In case you ask about why my edition, it was because you had forgotten to write $d^4$ in the second equation of your third method. (which is the first I am studing)

The only solutions are $1306$, $1676$ and $2427$.

Ok. Thank you @AlmaArjuna. Which software you used for this ?

A simple Python script running through all combinations for $(a, b, c, d)$.

We wish to solve the equation
$$a+b^2+c^3+d^4 = \overline{(abcd)}_{10}$$
Because of Fermat's little theorem we have $x^3\equiv x\pmod 3$. Thus, analyzing it $\pmod 3$ we get
$$\begin{aligned}
a+b^2+c^3+d^4 &\equiv a+b+c+d &\pmod 3\\
b^2+d^2 &\equiv b+d &\pmod 3
\end{aligned}$$
This can only happen if $b, d\equiv 0, 1\pmod 3$ so we can't have $b, d = 2, 5, 8$.

We have
$$\begin{aligned}
a+b^2+c^3+d^4 &= 1000a+100b+10c+d&\implies\\
d^4-d &= 999a+100b-b^2+10c-c^3
\end{aligned}$$
Now notice

The minimum of $999a$ in $[1, 9]$ is $999$ for $a = 1$
The minimum of $100b-b^2$ in $[0, 9]$ is $0$ for $b = 0$
The minimum of $10c-c^3$ in $[0, 9]$ is $-639$ for $c = 9$

This means $d^4-d = 999a+100b-b^2+10c-c^3$ is at least $999-639 = 360$. Thus, $d > 4$.

This narrows $d$ down to the set $\{6, 7, 9\}$. We'll test each one of these values. Once we reach a point where we have two unknowns in our equation we can start testing values, since there are at most $10$ possibilities for each unknown. Notice we don't need to test every pair, we can just substitute a single unknown and solve for the other one.

If $d = 9$, then
$$6561 = 9^4 < \overline{(abcd)}_{10} < 9+9^2+9^3+9^4 = 7380$$
so $a = 6$ or $a = 7$.

If $a = 6$, the equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
6+b^2+c^3+6561 &= 6000+100b+10c+9\\
b^2+c^3+558 &= 100b+10c
\end{aligned}$$
There is no solution.
If $a = 7$, the equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
7+b^2+c^3+6561 &= 7000+100b+10c+9\\
b^2+c^3 &= 441+100b+10c
\end{aligned}$$
There is no solution.


If $d = 7$, then
$$2401 = 7^4 < \overline{(abcd)}_{10} < 9+9^2+9^3+7^4 = 3220$$
so $a = 2$ or $a = 3$.

If $a = 2$, the equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
2+b^2+c^3+2401 &= 2000+100b+10c+7\\
b^2+c^3+396 &= 100b+10c
\end{aligned}$$
The only solution is $b = 4$ and $c = 2$.
If $a = 3$, the equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
3+b^2+c^3+2401 &= 3000+100b+10c+7\\
b^2+c^3 &= 603+100b+10c
\end{aligned}$$
There is no solution.


If $d = 6$, then
$$1296 = 6^4 < \overline{(abcd)}_{10} < 9+9^2+9^3+6^4 = 2115$$
so $a = 1$ or $a = 2$.

If $a = 1$, the equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
1+b^2+c^3+1296 &= 1000+100b+10c+6\\
b^2+c^3+291 &= 100b+10c
\end{aligned}$$
The only solutions are $b = 3$ and $c = 0$ or $b = 6$ and $c = 7$.
If $a = 2$, the equation becomes
$$\begin{aligned}
2+b^2+c^3+1296 &= 2000+100b+10c+6\\
b^2+c^3 &= 708+100b+10c
\end{aligned}$$
There is no solution.


The final answer for $\overline{(abcd)}_{10}$ are $2427$, $1306$ and $1676$.

By elementary remarks we reduce the following values (some of them figurent in comments above):
$$0\le a\le6;\space \space b\ne 2,5,8;\space \space 3\le d\ne5,8$$
then, because of $$999a=(b^2-100b)+(c^3-10c)+(d^4-d)$$ we get the following table
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}\text{digit}&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline999a&&999&1998&2997&3996&4995&5994&&&\\\hline b^2-100b&0&-99&&-291&-384&&-564&-651&&-819\\\hline c^3-10c&0&-9&-12&-3&24&75&156&273&432&639\\\hline d^4-d&&&&78&252&&1290&2394&&6552\\\hline\end{array}$$ now, since $999=27\times37$ we transform this table modulo $37$ which yields
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}\text{digit}&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\\hline999a&&0&0&0&0&0&0&&&\\\hline b^2-100b&0&12&&5&-14&&-9&15&&-5\\\hline c^3-10c&0&-9&-12&-3&13&1&8&14&-12&10\\\hline d^4-d&&&&4&-7&&-5&-11&&3\\\hline\end{array}$$
where I have put each module class $37$ with minimum absolute value in order to achieve the required null sum at a glance. This easily produces the only three numbers $306,676$ and $427$ according with the three red lines in the following figure:

Now the equations $$a+3^2+6^4=1000a+306\\a+6^2+7^3+6^4=1000a+676\\a+4^2+2^3+7^4=1000a+427$$ give the values $a=1,2$ already known by comments and answer before.
